# mongodb aggregation match multiple $and on the same field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a document like this :

```
{
    "ExtraFields" : [
    {
        "value" : "print",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ea")
    },
    {
        "value" : "14",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0eb")
    },
    {
        "value" : "POLYE",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ec")
    },
    {
        "value" : "30",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ed")
    },
    {
        "value" : "0",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ee")
    },
    {
        "value" : "0",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627731efa0843554b0ef")
    },
    {
        "value" : "0",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f0")
    },
    {
        "value" : "42",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f1")
    },
    {
        "value" : "30",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f2")
    },
    {
        "value" : "14",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f3")
    },
    {
        "value" : "19",
        "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f4")
    }
],
        "id" : ObjectId("55369e60733e4914550832d0"), "title" : "A product"
}
```

what i want is to match one or more sets from the ExtraFields array. For example, all the products that contain the values print and 30. Since a value may be found in more than one fieldID (like 0 or true) we need to create a set like

```
WHERE (fieldID : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ea"), value : "print")
```

Where i'm having problems is when querying more than one fields. The pipeline i came up with is :

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$ExtraFields'},

{
    '$match': {
        '$and': [{
            '$and': [{'ExtraFields.value': {'$in': ["A52A2A"]}}, {
                'ExtraFields.fieldID': ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ea")
            }]
        }

            ,
            {
                '$and': [{'ExtraFields.value': '14'}, {'ExtraFields.fieldID': ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0eb")}]
            }

        ]
    }
},


]);
```

This returns zero results, but this is what i want to do in theory. Match all items that contain set 1 AND all that contain set 2.

The end result should look like a faceted search output :

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "values" : "18",
            "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f3")
        },
        "count" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "values" : "33",
            "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627831efa0843554b0f2")
        },
        "count" : 1
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: done, i've added the expected output.

Comment: if I understand you want to count distinct subdocument in `ExtraFields` right?

Answer (score 9):

You could try the following aggregation pipeline

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "ExtraFields.value": { "$in": ["A52A2A", "14"] },
            "ExtraFields.fieldID": { 
                "$in": [
                    ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ea"),
                    ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0eb")
                ] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$ExtraFields"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "ExtraFields.value": { "$in": ["A52A2A", "14"] },
            "ExtraFields.fieldID": { 
                "$in": [
                    ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0ea"),
                    ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0eb")
                ] 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "value": "$ExtraFields.value",
                "fieldID": "$ExtraFields.fieldID"
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

With the sample document provided, this gives the output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "value" : "14",
                "fieldID" : ObjectId("5535627631efa0843554b0eb")
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: this will not work, you really need the fieldID. Value 0 can exist in multiple fieldID's, so can 14 and so can any value. The right thing to do is create pairs of value AND fieldID

Comment: it's better, but i see a problem with it. The result is not an AND, more like an OR. In your example, i got back correct individual counts, but what i was expecting was combined counts. So, when you have applied the A52A2A for example, you get 5 for it (which is correct) and a count of 34 for 14 (which is the individual count) where i should be getting a 2 which is the combined count (all products that are of color A52A2A and have a property of 14). You can check how i expect it to work here http://goo.gl/u4WTfY (it was done in ES) and the json i work with here https://goo.gl/uZJ9xK